# Docker build command for Dockerfile not in current directory

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried everything, looked up at least 20 similar questions, non could solve it.

I need a docker build command that reads my docker file nested inside the directory.

Docker file is located
`\Test\Backend\App%20Server\Dev\Test\Application`

I have tried the following command none worked

`docker build -t test-app -f . Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application/Dockerfile`

`docker build -t test-app . Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application/Dockerfile`

`docker build -t test-app -f Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application/Dockerfile`

`docker build -t test-app -f . Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application`

Note: my Dockfile has the default name

Error returned

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
docker build -t test-app Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm missing something.
Have you tried to move first in your directory, then build the image?

```
cd \Test\Backend\App%20Server\Dev\Test\Application
docker build -t test-app .
```

Comment: I am putting in the GitHub Action command, thus, may not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either:

```sh
docker build -t test-app -f Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application/Dockerfile . #dot after the parameters
```

or

```sh
docker build . -t test-app -f Test/Backend/App%20Server/Dev/Test/Application/Dockerfile #dot before the parameters
```

Comment: Hi @Lucas, I am getting error `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: resolve :`

Comment: hi @Jim_Mcdonalds, if you are using GitHub action might be an issue with your Dockerfile file name, check [here](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/415). You might need to rename to `Dockerfile` or `dockerfile`